Can't get optional images to display in \NewDocumentCommand
I'm working on a file to compile minutes of a meeting.  The final part of the document consists of the officers' reports, where each report is an 8.5x11" PDF image.  Most of them are single pages, but one never is.  I tried this command,
\NewDocumentCommand{\report}{m m m o o}{
\section{#1}
\label{app:#2}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{Reports/#3.pdf}
\end{center}
\IfValueT{#4}{
\clearpage
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{Reports/#4.pdf}
\end{center}
}
\IfValueT{#5}{
\clearpage
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{Reports/#5.pdf}
\end{center}
}
}

Argument 1 is the appendix title (mandatory); argument 2 is the label name (mandatory); argument 3 is the image file name without PDF extension (mandatory).  The next two are optional image names (without the PDF extension) for multipage-reports.
The command works for single page reports.  When I have a three page report, invoked with the command
\report{Executive Director's Report}{director}{director1}{director2}{director3}

the image director1.pdf is displayed as expected.  But director2.pdf and director3.pdf are not.  Instead, I see only director2director3 on the page that follows the one displaying director1.pdf.  Any suggestions?

arguments 4 and 5 are declared as o so should be in [] not {} if they are used.

welcome! I think you'd find this easier with pdfpages.

Thank you so much, David.  The square brackets did the trick!  Now I will check out pdfpages.
